# GODI-Batteries: Installation problems

Tags: installation, ocaml, godi, ocaml-batteries

I am trying to install godi-batteries using GODI console. I seem to have all dependencies sorted (like Camomile). I get the following error within Godi's interface:

```
    > ocamlfind ocamlopt -shared -linkall -package camomile,num,str -o src/batteries_uni.cmxs src/batteries_uni.cmxa
    > + ocamlfind ocamlopt -shared -linkall -package camomile,num,str -o src/batteries_uni.cmxs src/batteries_uni.cmxa
    > ld: warning: -read_only_relocs cannot be used with x86_64
    > ld: codegen problem, can't use rel32 to external symbol _caml_negf_mask in .L101 from src/batteries_uni.a(batFloat.o)
    > collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    > File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
    > Error: Error during linking
    > Command exited with code 2.
    > make[7]: *** [all] Error 10
    > Error: Exec error: File /Users/surikator/godi/build/godi/godi-batteries/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1039: Command returned with non-zero exit code
    > Error: Exec error: File /Users/surikator/godi/build/godi/godi-batteries/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1378: Command returned with non-zero exit code
```

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.4. and I have a 64 bit machine.

Any ideas on how to go around this?

Thanks,
Surikator.

Comment: Can you post more of the output log? That smells like Batteries is somehow building incorrectly, perhaps building 32-bit when it should be 64.  More output might shed light on whether it's a GODI problem or a Batteries problem.  I seem to remember various problems cropping up as Batteries is used on the Mac.

Comment: @Michael I edited my question and added two lines above and the last two lines, also. What is missing before is a huge set of calls to `ocamlfind ocamlopt`. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael OK, I found this (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ocaml.godi/462) and by changing the option of shared libraries to "no" in godi console, it passed through that part. What potential problems can having it as a non-shared library bring?

Comment: What you'll be missing is the ability to dynamically load Batteries in native-code projects.  This capability isn't used very often (it's primarily for things like Ocsigen).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, OSX OCaml can't build shared libraries.  You'll have to disable batteries' building of shared libraries with

```
BATTERIES_NATIVE_SHLIB=no make
```

This problem has been fixed in git commit [92b323](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/commit/92b3239846173d3c0ac2009a5646b9fe44729ce3#Makefile), and will be included in the next release.